# Go Template if value is set and is false

Tags: go, if-statement, templates, go-templates

I am using [Listmonk](https://listmonk.app/docs/templating/) which utilizes Go Templates. I have a situation where a variable for user status (`.Subscriber.Attribs.Pro`) may exist (and if it does, it is `true` or `false`. I want to display a block of text only if the value exists.

The code I have works if the `Pro` attribute is set. However if it is not set, it will be processed as `not ''` which leads to a value of `true`.

```
{{ if not .Subscriber.Attribs.Pro }}
  You are not a Pro user!
{{ end }}
```

How do I have this code run only if the `Pro` attribute is explicitly set to `false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically you only want to display the text if `.Subscriber.Attribs.Pro` is supplied and is `false`. So do a comparison:

```
{{ if eq false .Subscriber.Attribs.Pro }}
    You are not a Pro user!
{{ end }}
```

We can test it like:

```
t := template.Must(template.New("").Parse("{{ if eq false .Pro }}You are not a Pro user!\n{{ end }}"))

fmt.Println("Doesn't exist:")
if err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, nil); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Println("Pro is false:")
m := map[string]interface{}{
    "Pro": false,
}
if err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, m); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Println("Pro is true:")
m["Pro"] = true
if err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, m); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/A2bE3YDOVwV)):

```
Doesn't exist:
Pro is false:
You are not a Pro user!
Pro is true:
```

As you can see, the body of the `{{if}}` block is only executed when `Pro` is explicitly set to `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the included [Sprig](https://masterminds.github.io/sprig/dicts.html) hasKey function:

```
{{if hasKey .Subscriber.Attribs "Pro"}}
    {{ if not .Subscriber.Attribs.Pro }}
        You are not a Pro user!
     {{ end }}
{{ end }}
```